# Laravel multiple file upload

Tags: laravel, file, laravel-5

I am trying to upload files (they can be any type), and I have a problem uploading file with certain way.

I am able to upload a file correctly using `$request->file('file_name')` and `Storage::disk($disk)->put($path, $file);`. However, `$file` parameter can only be through `$request->file('file_name')`.

However, because of the way I want to upload multiple orders with multiple files like below:

**Controller**

```
foreach ( $filesArray as $key => $files ) {

    $path = 'order/'.$order->id;

    if ( isset($files[$i]) && !empty($files[$i]) ) {
        for ( $j = 0; $j < count($files[$i]); $j++ ) {
            $uploadedFile = FileHelper::upload($files[$i][$j], $path);

            $orderFile = [];
            $orderFile['order_id'] = $order->id;
            $orderFile['file_id'] = $uploadedFile->id;
            OrderFileModel::create($orderFile);
        }
   }
}
```

**FileHelper**

```
static public function upload($file, $path, $disk = 's3')
{
    $fileOrm = new FileModel;
    $fileOrm->size = $file->getSize();
    $fileOrm->extension = $file->getExtension();
    $fileOrm->bucket_name = self::$BUCKET_NAME;
    $fileOrm->type = self::getFileType($file->getExtension());
    $fileOrm->key = Storage::disk($disk)->put($path, $file);
    $fileOrm->created_time = now();
    $fileOrm->save();

    return $fileOrm;
}
```

I've also attached images where I see the difference.
One with `$request->file('file_name')` and the other with just `$request->file_name` which is blob type.

[image: able to upload]

[image: not able to upload: with error fstat() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given]

The image below would return error saying `fstat() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given`

How could I solve this problem?

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: are you able to refactor the fileHelper::upload method to include the request object? Or, can you call the request() helper method in the upload method? If so, you can use laravel's built in file handler `$path = $request->file('avatar')->store(
    'avatars/'.$request->user()->id, 's3'
);`  ?  Otherwise you'll need to use something like file_get_contents($files[$i][$j]) to get the contents of the temp file and handle it manually.

Comment: @j.steelman thanks for the comment. How would I use `file_get_contents` to get the contents? According to the doc, `file_get_contents` required the name of the file in the first parameter, however `$files[$i][$j]` is an object.

Comment: @smchae User [this package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) and upload any number of files with any type easily in one line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you get your file list to use `$request->files`? If you do, change to `$request->allFiles()`. This method will convert `File` object to `UploadedFile` object.

Answer (score 3):

Actually just put an array in your input file like this

```
<input type="file" name="files[]">
<input type="file" name="files[]">
<input type="file" name="files[]">
<input type="file" name="files[]">
```

**NOTE: you need to enctype="multipart/form-data" enabled in your form.**

Then in your controller, you can loop the input file by doing such

```
foreach($request->file('files') as $index => $file){
    // do uploading like what you are doing in your single file.
}
```

Comment: I am trying to several sequences of uploading multiple files. So, I have to get those files in array form, then loop through that array and access each file for each action(order creation)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'files.*' => 'file|mimes:...'
]);

foreach ($request->files as $file) {
    $fileName = (string)Str::uuid() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    try {
        if (\Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileName, file_get_contents($file))) {
            FileModel::create([
                'size'         => '...',
                'extension'    => '...',
                'bucket_name'  => '...',
                'type'         => '...',
                'key'          => '...',
                'created_time' => '...'
            ]);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have been lucky before that some type casting on your $image object made a string out of it, I guess a simple chnage of your last line to

```
$disk->put($path, $file->__toString());
```

will fix the problem and is safer anyway as the "put" method officially only accepts strings (and looking at the implmentation also php resources). That should keep you compatible to changes in the long run.

Comment: can u able to print it ? $file->__toString() ?